# I can't get the text input off the bottom of the table header

Tags: html, css, input, textbox

So I suck at CSS and haven't done much HTML since before CSS existed... So I'm trying to learn by doing... I have searched and tried several things to get this to work but nothing works... I want to have my "search" box centered vertically in the table header. How do I achieve this? I've tried margin settings and other suggestions I've read on this site so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong I don't see. Hopefully you can help... I will need specific instructions like where to put the code on the page too. Thanks for your help! Here is what I have.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Have A Voice - Speak Up!</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body{
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    border-spacing;0px;
    space:0px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding: 0;
}  
    #my_input {
    height;100%;
}
#my_table {
    table-layout:fixed;
}
#search{
    border:red solid 1px;
    height:50px; 
    display:table-cell; 
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:top
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#b2b2b2">
<table width=100% height=706 border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td height="50" align="center" nowrap="nowrap" background="Images/LeftHeader2.png">&nbsp;</td>
            <td background="Images/HeaderCenter2.png" colspan="3" height="50" align="leftr"><a href="index.html"><img src="Images/HaveAVoiceLogo.png" height="50" border="0"/></a>&nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="search" placeholder="Search" results="0" border="0" /></td>
            <td height="50" align="center" background="Images/LeftHeader2.png">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" rowspan="3" align="center" nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="10%" rowspan="3" align="center">Menu</td>
          <td width="80%"height="450" colspan="2" align="center">Video Frame</td>
          <td width="5%" rowspan="3" align="center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="50" align="center">Like Vote Rate</td>
          <td width="10%" rowspan="2" align="center"><p>More</p>
        Videos</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="250" align="center">Comment</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="50" colspan="5" align="center" nowrap="nowrap">Footer</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you put your thoughts into a specific question? :)

Comment: You should look into `div` layouts.  It's not considered good practice to use `table`s for layout.  Side note, in your CSS you have a `;` as opposed to `:` for `#my_table`'s height, and `body`'s border-spacing.

Comment: Thanks... working on it... I'm oldschool html coder and still haven't caught up... :)